# EF 4 delete many to many object

Tags: entity-framework, many-to-many

I am trying to delete an object from a many to many relationship but it refused to get worked.

The structure is as follows:

I have a **Products** table which every product has **excProducts**

I am trying to delete an excProduct with the following code

```
var objectContx = new objectContx();
var prod = objectContx.Products.Where(p => p.ProductID == prodID).FirstOrDefault();
var excProd = objectContx.ExcProducts.Where(exc => exc.ExcProductID == excProdid).FirstOrDefault();
prod.ExcProducts.Attach(excProd);
prod.ExcProducts.Remove(excProd);
objectContx.SaveChanges();
```

The **excProd** deleted from database but when I am getting the **Product** from objectContext it has the deleted excProd in it's list.

How could I delete it from the objectContext as well?

Answer (score 0):

If your many to many relationship has an entity (e.g. if it has payload) then the instance of that entity must be deleted. This can be done manually or using cascaded delete (see option in property window while standing on relationship in EDMX designer).

Comment: Varod doesn't deleted the instance by executing the Remove(T) method? If not, how could I delete it (I prefer not using cascade). Thanks

Comment: Hi, first of all, please rephrase the question - unfortunately I did not understand the grammar. Second of all, Danny is my first name. :-)

Comment: Wrong copy paste for you name. In my subject, how could I delete the instance? I thought that the Remove(T) method deletes the instance. Doesn't it?

Comment: Add an image or description of the names and relations of your relevant entities.